# set and get the value of different class members in a class

Tags: c++, member-functions

i am very new to c++ programming and i have written a simple class program to display the name and duration of the project.

```
#include<iostream>
class project
{

public: 
std::string name;
int duration; 
};

int main ()
{
project thesis;  // object creation of type class
thesis.name = "smart camera"; //object accessing the data members of its class
thesis.duration= 6;

std::cout << " the name of the thesis is" << thesis.name << ;
std::cout << " the duration of thesis in months is" << thesis.duration;
return 0;
```

But now i need to program the same paradigm with get and set member functions of the class. I need to program somewhat like

```
#include<iostream.h>

class project
{

std::string name;
int duration; 

void setName ( int name1 ); // member functions set 
void setDuration( string duration1); 

};

void project::setName( int name1)

{

name = name1;

}


void project::setDuration( string duration1);

duration=duration1;

}

// main function

int main()
{
project thesis;  // object creation of type class

thesis.setName ( "smart camera" );
theis.setDuration(6.0);


//print the name and duration


return 0;

}
```

I am not sure whether above code logic is correct, can someone please help me how to proceed with it.
Thanks much

Comment: I believe you did it correct.

Comment: Looks good to me although it would nice if you would indent your code. Many folk use m_ as a prefix for member data in C++. Then you can use name rather than name1 etc.

Comment: But how to print the name and duration in the main function. do i need to print `std::cout << " the name of the thesis is" << thesis.name << ;` ? can you please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written some set functions. You now need some get functions.

```
int project::getName()
{
    return name;
}

std::string project::getDuration( )
{
    return duration;
}
```

Since the data is now private you cannot access it from outside the class. But you can use your get functions in your main function.

```
std::cout << " the name of the thesis is" << thesis.getName() << '\n';
std::cout << " the duration of the thesis is" << thesis.getDuration() << '\n';
```

Comment: thanks for your help. could you please update it has a full program. so that i will understand more clear.

Comment: Add the methods inside the class definition. Add the std::cout call instead of the comment "//print the name and duration"